# Azure Application gateway with web apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have setup an Azure Application Gateway in front of an Azure Web Application. I have added IP restriction on Web app to allow access only from the Application gateway's public IP address. This works fine but when I type the public IP address in the browser, it re-directs to the web app's URL. How can I stop the application gateway redirecting to the web app URL but to return the response against the public IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you first need to configure the custom domain to the webapp and once the propagation happens the CNAME record of the custom domain should be changed to map the FQDN of the Application gateway.

Comment: I did but still unable to access my application via url or ip of application gateway

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed MVC web application behind Application gateway with following settings and when I type Ip address of application gateway, it shows web application on application gateway IP

Custom probe was automatically added when I saved page after selecting "HTTPS" and "Use for App Service" option.

[image]

Backend pool where WebApp was selected

[image]

if you still see any issues then I will post steps to configure everything tomorrow.

Comment: I did the same but I cannot access my application, neither via IP or via url.